# Count distinct based on multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I've a dataset as shown below:

```
product_list <- tribble(
  ~shop_name, ~product_id, ~category,
  "A",         1,          "Game",
  "B",         2,          "Book",         
  "C",         3,          "Electronic",
  "A",         4,          "Home", 
  "A",         5,          "Game",
  "B",         3,          "Electronic",
  "C",         8,          "Home",
  "A",         6,          "Book",
  "A",         7,          "Game",
  "B",         7,          "Game",
)
```

But now I want to add a new column that shows us the number of categories per each shop and want to keep all other columns. Here is the desired result:

```
desired_list <- tribble(
  ~shop_name, ~product_id, ~category,        ~number_of_category
  "A",         1,          "Game",            3, 
  "B",         2,          "Book",            1,
  "C",         3,          "Electronic",      1,
  "A",         4,          "Home",            1,
  "A",         5,          "Game",            3,
  "B",         3,          "Electronic",      1,
  "C",         8,          "Home",            1,
  "A",         6,          "Book",            1,
  "A",         7,          "Game",            3,
  "B",         7,          "Game",            1,
)
```

Can someone help me to get the result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why C has 1 number_of_category, while C has categories `Electronic` and `Home`.

Comment: He is counting the number of times the combination "C" and "Electronic" appears, which is 1, and the number of times the combination "C" and "Home" appears, which is also 1. Only the combination "A" and "Game" occurs more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add counts with the `add_count` function, which, unlike `count` does not remove the other columns:

`product_list %>% add_count(shop_name, category, name = "number_of_category")`